# PHP: When echo a JavaScript alert, text input size decreases

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a basic HTML form like this. When submitted, it checks for empty fields and alert the user that both fields are required. After alert, user is redirected to the same page but text input sizes decrease. How can I retain the same width, height after PHP "echo"?

Screenhot 1:
[image: 1]

Screenshot 2:
[image: 2]

Screenshot 3:[image: 3]

**Controller:**

```
function validate_user_pass() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Email', 'required|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password', 'required|max_length[32]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {  
        //$this->load->view('login_error');
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Required fields are empty!");</script>';
        $this->index();
    }       
    else {
        $this->verify();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo form_open('login/validate_user_pass'); ?>
<div class="login">
<div class="login-screen">
    <div class="login-icon">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/1374606542_newsstand_ios7_ios_7.png" alt="logo">
        <h4>Hotel<small>Management System</small></h4>
    </div>
<div class="login-form">
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/ico/logo_small.png" alt="logo">
    <div class="control-group">
        <input type="text" class="login-field" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" placeholder="Enter username" id="login-name">
    </div>
        <div class="control-group">
        <input type="password" class="login-field" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="login-pass">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">

</div>
</div>
</div>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Cant see from your code but check you have closed all your tags, especially after submit

Comment: Yes. The code is fine. This happened to me on Twitter Bootstrap as well. But does not occur without CSS. Probably something with CSS.

Comment: Then post relevant css

Comment: I'm using a bootstrap http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/

Comment: My first impresssion is that something is added to the document which results in it breaking. Usually text inputs can behave like that if text is parsed before `<html>` for instance.

Comment: may be the page is not loading properly.Try to use $this->load->view();

Answer (score 1):

it may be late to answer but same problem was with me. I overcome this by putting the error popup box out of the header. I searched everywhere and ended up here.

My code was something like this before:

```
<?php
   //some code for verification and echo out/show error message
?>  
<html>

   <!--HTML code that has form-->
</html>
```

What I did was something like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <?php
       //some code for verification and echo out/show error message
    ?>
    <div>
       <!--HTML code that has form-->
    </div>
    </body
</html>
```

This problem mostly exist because of echo present in header part. You can check your views for this and that may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when a php error or var_dump() is on the page, but you may not see it because it is hidden under a fixed header div, for example.

Look at your View source & check if there aren't php errors on the page